# OpenVPN client is connecting to wrong IP address

Tags: openvpn

I setup an OpenVPN server but whenever I try to connect with the Windows 10 OpenVPN client I get the following error:

> There was an error attempting to connect to the selected server

Here's what I see in the logs:

```
⏎10/11/2021, 11:17:42 PM EVENT: WAIT ⏎10/11/2021, 11:17:42 PM Connecting to [3.133.152.18]:1194 (3.133.152.18) via UDPv4
⏎10/11/2021, 11:17:46 PM Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
```

It's timing out. I can see why it's timing out - the IP address it's trying to connect to is wrong. If I do `ping vpn.neubert.com` I get `3.142.17.247`. Even the server admin shows 3.142.17.247:

[image]

So why is the OpenVPN client trying to connect to 3.133.152.18?

Comment: What is in your client config file?

Comment: @NiKiZe - where do I find that? I'm using the OpenVPN GUI client from https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/. I don't see anything that looks like a config file in C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect..

Comment: @NiKiZe - the only files that start with a c in that directory are: ca.pak, content_resources_200_percent.pak and content_shell.pak

Comment: Well you should start with verifying which settings are in your client, I'm not familiar with that client, but maybe you could try the documentation for the client.

Comment: Without the client config we can't say anything. We all are familliar with the open source product called "OpenVPN Community". You're using the paid product based on it, "OpenVPN Access Server", probably this problem is triggered by some additional functions they implemented in it. Have you tried contacting their tech support (otherwise why would you have bought it)?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - I'm not paying for it. At the very least I see no evidence that I am. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNQJZ.jpg . I think it's free for the first two users.

Comment: This doesn't change anything for us, only for you. We need the openvpn configuration config file or command line (it can be configured fully via cmdline parameters without any config file).

Comment: So this has happened in my company, i set up a vpn, some new sysadmin came along and changed the company ip address public facing, and now what's happening is every client ovpn certificate is being generated with the old ip address. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the profile and recreate it to get the updated IP address in the client